# Identifying links in message body for view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, database-design

I have a rails app where users can talk to each other via chat. If they send over links in the chat (if you send anything at the moment in the chat it gets saved as message.body) to each other I would like to somehow distinguish it from plain text to be able to show the links on an index page later. How could I do that? At the moment 2 users have one common conversation. And messages belong to conversation.

Should I try to save them as different message attribute like message.link? If yes, then how can I distinguish message.link from message.body when creating the message. Or can I just simply use some helper method and showing only those message.body-s where the body itself is a link. And what if the half of the message is plain text and the other half is a link?

message schema

```
create_table "messages", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text     "body"
    t.integer  "conversation_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "message_attachment"
end
```

Comment: this may help you https://github.com/tenderlove/rails_autolink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Rinku`.](https://github.com/vmg/rinku)
1. Add it to your `gemfile`

```
gem 'rinku'
```

2. Create a method in your `ApplicationHelper` name it `find_links`

```
  def find_links(message_body)
     Rinku.auto_link(message_body, mode=:all, link_attr=nil, skip_tags=nil).html_safe 
  end
```

3. In your view pass the message body to the `find_links` method.

```
= find_links(message.body)
```

Comment: Mohamed, I could not find good resource (that I can understand) on it. Where should I pass this code?

Comment: Mohamed, do you know some good resources then? You would save my life. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have edited my answer to provide more detailed information about the approach.

Comment: Mohamed, thanks! It's working. It was just confusing to put Rinku.auto_link(message.body, mode=:all, link_attr=nil, skip_tags=nil).html_safe instead of message.body to the view

Comment: Mohamed, is it possible to save somehow the link? I mean there is a message.body = 'here is is: "http://......" I hope u like it" and I want to save only the link part of the message as message.link, so I can show it the users later.

Comment: Mohamed, could you pls answer my last comment? You would save my life. Thanks a lot!